# predict parameters of linear function

Tags: parameter-estimation

My questions seems very trivial, but I can't quite grasp it. I am also aware this post asks for opinions and knowhow, but do not know were else to ask. I do have quite a lot of experience solving even somewhat difficult machine learning problems, but never faced a situation were the target is still a parameter in an other function.

I have a function like:

t = ax + by + cz + bias.

And a database with t, x, y, z, m, n, o, p, etc. I expect the optimal a, b, c etc. to be functions of x, y, z, m, n, o, p. But since I do not know a,b,c, etc and only label/target t instead most machine learning methods from SKlearn do not work out of the box.

I though about first running a linear regression to find a, b, c, etc, that that loses all the information differentiating different datapoints. I guess a self coded SGD would be able to solve my issue, but do not know were to start. I also thought about just dropping my final function completly, but I want to conserve some of the information stored within the function.

For example I do know, that a is dependant on different parameters than b and can give a list to each. My thought is that I reduce possible overfitting by giving as many constraints as possible, espacially since my dataset is not that big.

Comment: Can you please explain why simple linear regression does not work for you?

Comment: I don't see exactly how to solve the problem but it makes me think of 2 directions: (1) maybe considering a,b,c as latent variables in an ad-hoc probabilistic model? (2) it looks a bit like an optimization problem, and from this point of view I'd explore if the problem can be represented with genetic learning.

Comment: I feel like there is some information stored in the fact that it is additive and that I know which parameters have influence on which coefficients, but you might be right, when you say just use one linear regression, since it is only a additive model anyway, which in and of itself can be very easily included in one linear regression and there should not be a need to make it into two steps.

Comment: It might be worth looking at it more like a simple optimization problem, thank you, Will have to look more into genetic learning, but this might be a very good tip.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to map your problem onto conventional linear regression:

$$ y = β_0 + B_1x_1 + B_2+x_2 + ε $$

In your case:

- $t$ would the numeric target values from the dataset.
- $a, b, c$ are the the coefficients/weights to estimate.
- $x, y, z$ are the features values from the dataset.
- $bias$ is the intercept term $B_0$ to estimate.

Once the dataset is properly formatted, [scikit-learn's linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) can be used to estimate the coefficients.

You are correct that estimating a model "loses all the information differentiating different datapoints". A model is a useful simplification of the data.